# user gets insufficient privileges

Tags: security, standard-objects

I cloned the standard user profile and took away rights to a lot of objects. However I left a few of the standard objects like contacts and accounts. When I give this profile to a user they get 'Insufficient Privileges' when they click on the accounts tab. 
Everything I see tells me they should have rights to accounts and contacts by giving them this profile but it does not work. The profile is using the standard 'salesforce' license. 
They can see campaigns, opportunities and leads other object I gave them rights too, although they actually have less access to those objects.

Any thoughts on what would be preventing them from seeing accounts or what I'm missing?

Accounts    Read, Create, Edit, Delete, View All    39  Default On  Account Layout

Comment: wht does the account url look like when you click on account tab? .../001/o or something like /apex/...

Comment: I don't suppose you set the Account tab to Hidden?

Comment: That was it Rao. It's coming back with /apex/{customvfpage}.

Comment: I have to dealt with silliness in the past :) Glad I could help

Comment: I guess the previous guy wanted to change the default tab layout for accounts and contacts and I didn't even notice that it was redirecting to /apex.  Was beating my head against wall on that one and totally looking in the wrong place. Great call thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you have is a visualforce tab

Go to setup--> Develop --> Visualforce pages --> look for the page --.> click on security under action. and from the list of available profiles add the user profile in context to the enabled profiles

[image]